# TYPO3 10 RTE ckeditor images

Tags: image, ckeditor, typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

How can I enable the common image select dialog in ckeditor? The extension rte_ckeditor_image isn't available for TYPO3 10.

I didn't found anything. Isn't there no one needing this?

Answer (score 4):

Normal images have no place in the CKEditor, as these can then no longer be processed by the TYPO3 system and optimized for responsive design.
Small images are often only pictograms and can be integrated as icon fonts using CSS classes.
Therefore the need is small.

Comment: I see it the same as Sven: you should avoid images in RTE if possible. But if you really need the extension, it should be fairly easy to update it for v10. I just did a quick scan with `typo3scan` and there are only very few places where you need to update. So you can either fork the extension and do the update by yourself. Or you get in touch with the extension author and ask if an update is planned. Some sponsoring might help in that case.

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right. But I can't upgrade from TYPO3 9 to 10 now. And I can already hear the voice "_Why didn't you do that with **WordPress**?_". @PeterKraume I will try your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: @RenéTeinze Good joke about WP. Made my day :D and more seriously, actually just tested with TYPO3 ver.: `9.5.19` and `10.4.5`. Images in CKE are disabled within configuration `typo3/sysext/rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml`  with `removePlugins: - image` so you'll need to override the config to remove that _removing_.  CKE images will work. Disadvantage of this is that doesn't support advanced file handling with FAL, you'll need to add strict URI for each image, but I think it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

But there is a branch on [GitHub](https://github.com/netresearch/t3x-rte_ckeditor_image) supporting TYPO3 v10. You can [download the dev-TYPO3_10.x branch](https://github.com/netresearch/t3x-rte_ckeditor_image/archive/dev-TYPO3_10.x.zip) as a zip file and place it in your `typo3conf/ext` in a folder named `rte_ckeditor_image`.

If you are using composer, you can try to use `composer req netresearch/rte-ckeditor-image:dev-TYPO3_10.x`.

If you have a composer installation and `composer req` fails (as it did in my case) you can try the following.

1. Download extension as mentioned above.
2. Add the autoload line(s) to your

`composer.json`

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Netresearch\\RteCKEditorImage\\": "public/typo3conf/ext/rte_ckeditor_image/Classes/"
        }
    }
}
```

3. Run `composer install`
4. Activate the extension in *Extension Manager*
5. Follow the [installation instruction](https://github.com/netresearch/t3x-rte_ckeditor_image/tree/dev-TYPO3_10.x#installation) of rte_ckedit_image
6. Clear TYPO3 Cache in *Maintenance*

There are currently waiting 2 pull requests that might have some updates.

- [WIP: Dev TYPO3 10.x](https://github.com/netresearch/t3x-rte_ckeditor_image/pull/98) what will bring the v10 version to production
- [Dev typo3 10.x](https://github.com/netresearch/t3x-rte_ckeditor_image/pull/101) what simply resolves the conflicts in WIP: Dev TYPO3 10.x